# WIX.com Primary key to be used as reference

Tags: velo

I'm new to the WIX web development platform.

I need to use the Primary Key of Table 1  to be used as a reference of Table 2, but I cannot use the ID of table 1 for this purpose.

I wonder if the best way is to "copy" this ID in the Title field (Primary Key) of this table 1. How I do that? Is this the best method?

Thank you,
Arturo

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Arturo:

Have you tried doing this without using wix code?
Check out [this post](https://support.wix.com/en/article/working-with-multiple-item-reference-fields) to see if it is possible.

Now in code the only way to add a reference field from another data collection is to use the ID. But note that ID is the field name used in the data collection for dashboard and Editor view. When accessing the ID value in code you need to use the field key which is ***_id***.

So in your Table2 you need a column (field) that is of type reference and give it a field name like "Table1 Reference". The editor will generate a field key for you that will look like **table1Reference**.

Now if you have a record from Table1 that you want to link to Table2 you do something like this:

```
wixData.query('Table1')
.eq('title', 'uniqueTitle')
.find()
.then((results) => {
    if (results.totalCount !== 1) {
        throw Error('We didn't get a record from Table1');
    }
    // Success add this in a new record in Table2
    let table1Item = results.items[0];
    let table2Data = {
        table1Reference:table1Item._id,
        anotherTable2Field:"Some info for table2"
    };
    return wixData.save('Table2', table2Data)
    .then((savedRecord) => {
        // Successful save!
        // Do something here....
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Good luck!
Steve

Comment: Thank you Steve.I'll try it.
 It looks not as easy as in MS Access or in SQL Server where this procedure is automatic.
It is a hard learning curve!
Arturo

Comment: You are welcome. I think you can simplify the ***table2Data*** also by simply assigning the whole **table1Item** and drop the **'._id'** as the api will figure it out.   I suppose comparing technologies can be tough. I suspect if you were to read and write to a SQLSever database using javascript you would encounter similar syntax. Anyway hope this works for you!